# Procedure oracle para copiar dados entre tabelas

Tags: oracle, select, procedure, stored-procedures

Necessito fazer uma procedure que copie da minha tabela TAB_FORNECEDOR, tudo o que tem nela e passe pra tabela TAB_FORNECEDOR2.

Sei que preciso fazer um cursor com loop, um delete com commit antes de tudo, podem me dar uma luz de como montar minha procedure?

Comment: Olá gustavo, bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Ajustei seu título para ficar mais condizente com a dúvida levantada. Caso queira pode reverter minha edição.

Comment: Já fizeste alguma coisa? Poste um trecho do seu código

Answer (score 5):

Uma solução é criar a tabela do zero com os dados da anterior:

```
CREATE TABLE
   TAB_FORNECEDOR2
AS
   SELECT
      *
   FROM
      TAB_FORNECEDOR;
```

Lembrando que para isso você deve remover a TAB_FORNECEDOR2 caso já exista.

Se apenas precisa manter as duas sincronizadas, melhor dar mais detalhes na pergunta.

**Importante**: se você precisar definir *constraints* na cópia, terá que fazer isso manualmente, pois o `CREATE AS` não copia os índices, triggers, etc.

Se quiser copiar apenas os dados, pode usar esta sintaxe:

```
INSERT INTO
   TAB_FORNECEDOR2 (
      campo1,
      campo2
      ...
   )
SELECT
   TAB_FORNECEDOR.campo1 ...
FROM
   TAB_FORNECEDOR
```

E opcionalmente pode usar um `WHERE` para filtrar as linhas desejadas.

Comment: Tenho que fazer uma proc que pegue os campos da tabela
"FORNECEDOR" e copie para a tabela "FORNECEDORES2", mas eu tenho que criar uma proc que copie apenas campos de uma tabela para outra.